# Database connection "Mysql" is missing while baking with CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-bake

I am baking Models in CakePHP through baking command

```
 ./cake bake model all
```

I have configure database.php correctly.

```
    public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'mydb',
    'prefix' => '',
    //'encoding' => 'utf8',
);
```

I am getting this error while baking Models

```
#0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/febrics/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php(262): Mysql->connect()
#1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/febrics/lib/Cake/Model/ConnectionManager.php(107): DboSource->__construct(Array)
#2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/febrics/lib/Cake/Console/Command/Task/ModelTask.php(900): ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default')
#3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/febrics/lib/Cake/Console/Command/Task/ModelTask.php(837): ModelTask->getAllTables('default')
#4 /opt/lampp/htdocs/febrics/lib/Cake/Console/Command/Task/ModelTask.php(123): ModelTask->listAll('default', false)
#5 /opt/lampp/htdocs/febrics/lib/Cake/Console/Command/Task/ModelTask.php(102): ModelTask->all()
#6 /opt/lampp/htdocs/febrics/lib/Cake/Console/Shell.php(389): ModelTask->execute()
#7 /opt/lampp/htdocs/febrics/lib/Cake/Console/Shell.php(386): Shell->runCommand('execute', Array)
#8 /opt/lampp/htdocs/febrics/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(202): Shell->runCommand('model', Array)
#9 /opt/lampp/htdocs/febrics/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(68): ShellDispatcher->dispatch()
#10 /opt/lampp/htdocs/febrics/app/Console/cake.php(37): ShellDispatcher::run(Array)
#11 {main}
```

Please let me know where I am wrong.
THANKS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change localhost to 127.0.0.1

For some reason when using localhost it doesn't work via the command line while baking.

Answer (score 1):

We normally run into this problem when we are switching the configurations based on the HOST in the database.php file.

Are you trying to switch the database anywhere? Note that $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] is not available from command-line.